# Merge nested arrays when using $group when aggregating in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, group

I'm struggling to get to grips with the [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group) function to reconstruct my data after [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)ing to do [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)s. I'm quite new to MongoDB and I think I've got a fairly decent grasp of aggregations, but I've obviously hit a blind spot.

I've tried various [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group)  and [$map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) variations, and I'm struggling to get the output I'm looking for. A few pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated

Here is the data that I'm trying to reconstruct:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
        },
        "partNo": "1234567890",
        "description": "Big Disc",
        "project": "Disc Project",
        "objectType": "Part",
        "objectData": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebefa"
            },
            "status": "Approved",
            "object": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
            },
            "revision": "B",
            "customProperties": {
                "Number": "1234567890"
            },
            "files": [
                {
                    "description": "model",
                    "path": "../1234567890_OBJ_f60a76da/1234567890_.obj"
                }
            ],
            "quoteData": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "64148530fd344d312a07a274"
                },
                "quote":{
                    "reference": 1133,
                    "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                    "description": "Disc Project Pre-Production"
                },
                "quantity": 50,
                "quotedPrice": 15.06
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
        },
        "partNo": "1234567890",
        "description": "Big Disc",
        "project": "Disc Project",
        "objectType": "Part",
        "objectData": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebefa"
            },
            "status": "Approved",
            "object": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
            },
            "revision": "B",
            "customProperties": {
                "Number": "1234567890"
            },
            "files": [
                {
                    "description": "model",
                    "path": "../1234567890_OBJ_f60a76da/1234567890_.obj"
                }
            ],
            "quoteData": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "64148534fd344d312a07a2ad"
                },
                "quote":{
                    "reference": 1134,
                    "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                    "description": "Disc Project Production"
                },
                "quantity": 50,
                "quotedPrice": 11.6
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
        },
        "partNo": "1234567890",
        "description": "Big Disc",
        "project": "Disc Project",
        "objectType": "Part",
        "objectData": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebefa"
            },
            "status": "Approved",
            "object": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
            },
            "revision": "B",
            "customProperties": {
                "Number": "1234567890"
            },
            "files": [
                {
                    "description": "model",
                    "path": "../1234567890_OBJ_f60a76da/1234567890_.obj"
                }
            ],
            "quoteData": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "64149d15039c9fa0c91cf4ee"
                },
                "quote":{
                    "reference": 1132,
                    "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                    "description": "Disc Project test"
                },
                "quantity": 50,
                "quotedPrice": 11.6
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
        },
        "partNo": "1234567890",
        "description": "Big Disc",
        "project": "Disc Project",
        "objectType": "Part",
        "objectData": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "6414351e4eeee5bcf50ec148"
            },
            "status": "Approved",
            "object": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
            },
            "revision": "C",
            "customProperties": {
               "Number": "1234567890"
            },
            "files": [
                {
                    "description": "description",
                    "path": "path"
                }
            ],
            "quoteData": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "6415b34b03fcc9ccac3a7f22"
                },
                "quote":{
                    "reference": 1130,
                    "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                    "description": "Disc Project Prototype"
                },
                "quantity": 50,
                "quotedPrice": 11.7
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Using the objectData._id to group them I can't work out how to merge the quoteData into an array of quotes
and Here is how I'd like it to be output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
        },
        "partNo": "1234567890",
        "description": "Big Disc",
        "project": "Disc Project",
        "objectType": "Part",
        "objectData": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebefa"
            },
            "status": "Approved",
            "object": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
            },
            "revision": "B",
            "customProperties": {
                     "Number": "1234567890"
            },
            "files": [
                {
                    "description": "model",
                    "path": "../1234567890_OBJ_f60a76da/1234567890_.obj"
                }
            ],
            "quotes": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "64148530fd344d312a07a274"
                    },
                    "quote":{
                        "reference": 1133,
                        "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                        "description": "Disc Project Pre-Production"
                    },
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "quotedPrice": 15.06
                },
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "64148534fd344d312a07a2ad"
                    },
                    "quote":{
                        "reference": 1134,
                        "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                        "description": "Disc Project Production"
                    },
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "quotedPrice": 11.6
                },
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "64149d15039c9fa0c91cf4ee"
                    },
                    "quote":{
                        "reference": 1132,
                        "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                        "description": "Disc Project test"
                    },
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "quotedPrice": 11.6
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
        },
        "partNo": "1234567890",
        "description": "Big Disc",
        "project": "Disc Project",
        "objectType": "Part",
        "objectData": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "6414351e4eeee5bcf50ec148"
            },
            "status": "Approved",
            "object": {
                "$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"
            },
            "revision": "C",
            "customProperties": {
               "Number": "1234567890"
            },
            "files": [
                {
                    "description": "description",
                    "path": "path"
                }
            ],
            "quotes": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "6415b34b03fcc9ccac3a7f22"
                    },
                    "quote":{
                        "reference": 1130,
                        "company": "Disc Manufacturer Ltd",
                        "description": "Disc Project Prototype"
                    },
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "quotedPrice": 11.7
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What are the collections/schemas that you're starting with? What aggregation have you tried most recently? Why are you unwinding to do the lookups?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vpqjVkLZTWv

Here is a mongoplayground of my collections and aggregations up to this point.
Is there a way of doing lookups the way that I am without unwinding? I thought this wasn't possible

Answer (score 1):

As @user20042973 suggested, one option is to avoid unwinding, except when you really want to duplicate your documents, like you do on `objectData`:

```
db.objects.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"_id": {"$oid": "641435034eeee5bcf50ebef9"}}},
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "projects",
      "localField": "project",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [{"$project": {"name": 1, "_id": 0}}],
      "as": "projectName"
  }},
  {"$addFields": {project: {$first: "$projectName.name"}}},
  {"$unset": "projectName"},
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "objectTypes",
      "localField": "objectType",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [{"$project": {"name": 1, "_id": 0}}],
      "as": "objectTypeName"
  },
  {"$addFields": {"objectType": {$first: "$objectTypeName.name"}}},
  {"$unset": "objectTypeName"},
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "objectData",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "object",
      "as": "objectData"
  }},
  {"$unwind": "$objectData"},
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "quotedObjects",
      "localField": "objectData._id",
      "foreignField": "objectData",
      "pipeline": [{"$project": {"quantity": 1, "quotedPrice": 1, "quote": 1}}],
      "as": "objectData.quoteData"
  }},
  {"$lookup": {
      "from": "quotes",
      "localField": "objectData.quoteData.quote",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {"$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "url": {"$concat": [
                "../Quote.html?objectId=",
                {"$toString": "$_id"}
            ]},
            "company": 1,
            "description": 1,
            "reference": 1
        }}
      ],
      "as": "objectData.quotes"
  }},
  {"$set": {
      "objectData.quotes": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$objectData.quotes",
          "in": {"$mergeObjects": [
              {"$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$objectData.quoteData",
                  {"$indexOfArray": ["$objectData.quoteData.quote", "$$this._id"]}
              ]},
              {quote: {
                  reference: "$$this.reference",
                  company: "$$this.company",
                  description: "$$this.description",
                  url: "$$this.url"
              }}
          ]}
      }},
      "objectData.quoteData": "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QKeTybrfqB-)

You should also consider rethinking your schemas, as 5 `$lookup` on one query can be very inefficient. For example, from the current data only, I see no reason to keep `object`, `project`, `objectType`, `objectData` on different collections...Keeping them on one `objects` collection can be more efficient and avoid 3 "redundant" `$lookup`s...